# How to attach DataSource to UniGrid in Kentico

Tags: c#, kentico

How I can attach DataSource for UniGrid. I created custom filter and it works as expected with PagesDataSource and BasicRepeater web parts. But now I should get the same data source for UniGrid.

How I can do that ?

**UPDATE:**

Kentico version 8.2

ASCX:

```
<%@ Register Src="~/CMSAdminControls/UI/UniGrid/UniGrid.ascx" TagName="UniGrid" TagPrefix="cms" %>
<%@ Register Namespace="CMS.UIControls.UniGridConfig" TagPrefix="ug" Assembly="CMS.UIControls" %>

<cms:CMSDocumentsDataSource ID="myDocuments" runat="server" />
```

Code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InitializingDataSource();

    FrameGrid.DataSource = myDocuments.DataSource;
    FrameGrid.DataBind();
}

private void InitializingDataSource()
{
    myDocuments.FilterName = FilterName;
    myDocuments.Path = ContentPath;
    myDocuments.LoadCurrentPageOnly = true;
    myDocuments.LoadPagesIndividually = true;
    myDocuments.SelectOnlyPublished = true;
}
```

**UPDATE2:**

I removed DataBind but it is still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `UniGrid` is not a web part you can't bind it to the `PagesDataSource` web part. However you can still use the underlying server control `CMSDocumentsDataSource` (from `CMS.Controls` namespace). If you set up all its properties as if it was the `PagesDataSource` web part then it should work just fine. You can then bind UniGrid's `DataSource` property to it.

ASPX:

```
<%@ Register Src="~/CMSAdminControls/UI/UniGrid/UniGrid.ascx" TagName="UniGrid" TagPrefix="cms" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="ug" Namespace="CMS.UIControls.UniGridConfig" Assembly="CMS.UIControls, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=834b12a258f213f9" %>

<cms:CMSDocumentsDataSource runat="server" ID="src" Path="/%" />
<cms:UniGrid runat="server" ID="grd" DelayedReload="True">
    <GridColumns>
        <ug:Column Source="DocumentName" Name="DocumentName" runat="server" />
    </GridColumns>
</cms:UniGrid>
```

Codebehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    grd.DataSource = ((DataView)src.DataSource).Table.DataSet;
    grd.ReloadData();
}
```

Check out the documentation for [all possible ways of loading data](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K82/UniGrid) to the `UniGrid` and how to set it up using [ASPX markup and XML definition file](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K82/Reference+-+UniGrid+definition).

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I still need some help. I added <cms:CMSDocumentsDataSource ID="frameDocuments" runat="server" /> to ascx file and  set up it in Page_Load and set up my custom filter by FilterName property, but now my Kentico instance doesn't work with FrameGrid.DataSource = frameDocuments.DataSource; FrameGrid.DataBind(); configuration. Can you help me with that ?

Comment: No, can you help me with problem in previous comment ?

Comment: AFAIK there is no DataBind() method in UniGrid. Can you update your question with your ASPX markup + relevant codebehind? It would be also nice to know which version of Kentico do you use...

Comment: Should I delete DataBind method ?

Comment: The DataBind is not necessary - UniGrid will load the data during the Page_Load event

Comment: And where I should set this unigrid.DataSource = datasource.DataSource; ?

Comment: Check out the updated answer. I just tested it in Kentico 8.2. If you need any further customization see the documentation first, everything's in there.